# What is the minimum value for `interval_sec` and maximum value for `count` while configuring a rule for Security Policy in Google Cloud Armor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

While setting Rate Limit options to set rate-based throttling, the official documentation does not state the minimum value for interval_sec and the maximum value for `count`.

In the Google Cloud Console, the minimum value that can be set is 10 seconds for interval_sec, and via hit and trial, the maximum value reported by an error, for `count`, is 10000.

Would it correct to state 10k as the maximum value for `count`, and 10 seconds as the minimum value for `interval_sec`?

Answer (score 1):

Based from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview#throttle-traffic) the lowest given sample of interval_sec is 10. So if we are going to base the example from the documentation then the lowest will be 10.

Regarding the maximum value count. Since it was the result from your google console I believe that will be the right maximum value. Though I am not sure if using it will be the best practice. Based with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview#threshold_enforcement) everything will depend on your set up. Just like the example scenario from the shared documentation the limit is only set to 5000. For more information and understanding about this concern I suggest you visit the documentation I shared with you.